# Using <img> src in Ember cli

Tags: javascript, image, ember.js

I couldn't get an image to show up with Ember CLI. I tried to use the HTML `<img>` tag and made an exception in my environment file:

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
  'img-src': "'self' * all"
}
```

I used this `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="/public/images/image.png">
```

And I'm getting the following error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `<img src="/images/image.png"/>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not include the `public` directory when specifying the path.

Instead, just try the following:

`<img src="images/image.png">`

Answer (score -2):

```
<img src="assets/public/images/image.png">
```

please save your images in above path and give this path in img tag public folder contain your image path directory.